# Trouble with Intelij IDEA importing classes, "cannot find reference" but code still works - Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, intellij-idea, reference

I am having problems with Intelij IDEA (community edition 2019.3.3 with the latest updates). When I ty to import a class from a different .py file that I have made, it is red underlined and says "cannot find reference". The code still works fine but it is really annoying it doesnt give me options when I start typing .lives or .name etc

I have tried invalidate caches / restart but after it finishes indexing the problem is back, how could I sort this?

[image]

[image: folder hierarchy screen shot]

```
class Player:
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self._lives = 3
    self._level = 1
    self._score = 0
```

---

Main

```
from player import Player

kev = Player("Kevin")
print(kev.name)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how your project tree looks like?

Comment: Which version of the Python plugin do you use? Also, which interpreter version is configured for the project?

Comment: @Koyasha Hey, I hve updated the post to include the folder hierarchy screenshot, it is a bit complicated as I am doing a course and have just made new folders and put the .py files inside new folders, this is probably bad practice right? also I am not exactly sure which Python plugin I am using or which interpreter version is configured for the project. How can I check? Thanks!

Comment: Python plugin version can be found in the 'File | Settings | Plugins' dialog, 'Installed' tab. Check it against https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python/versions and update to the latest version if not already. Python configuration for your project can be checked in 'File | Project Structure'. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-python-sdk.html and its child pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: mark the 'Game' directory as a sources root (right-click on the folder > **Mark Directory as** > **Sources Root**). It should be colored blue.

More on content roots in IDEA: https://jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html